# getSupportFragmentManager() contains empty fragments after standby

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

After the device goes on standby, if I call  `getSupportFragmentManager()` I get a `FragmentManager` that contains fragments not initialised with all their variables set to `null`.

Here there is some code:

```
this.mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

this.mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
this.mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

TabPageIndicator titleIndicator = (TabPageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.titles);
titleIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
titleIndicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position)
    {
        mAdapter.getItem(position).onFocus();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0)
    {
    }
});
```

This is MyAdapter class:

```
public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{
    ArrayList<ExtendedFragment> tabs = new ArrayList<ExtendedFragment>();
    String[] titles = new String[] { "FRAG1", "FRAG2", "FRAG3", "FRAG4", "FRAG5", "FRAG6"};

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
    {
        super(fm);

        tabs.add(new frag1());
        tabs.add(new frag2());
        tabs.add(new frag3());
        tabs.add(new frag4());
        tabs.add(new frag5());
        tabs.add(new frag6());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return tabs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ExtendedFragment getItem(int position)
    {
        return tabs.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
    {
        return titles[position];
    }
}
```

The `ExtendedFragment` implements the method `onFocus()`, each fragment override that because i need to do some actions when a tab gets the focus. When I resume the device from standby and `onFocus()` is fired, if I try to get the `View` using `getView()` I get `null`.

Why my view is null?

Comment: Duplicate of your closed question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361801/getsupportfragmentmanager-strange-behaviour-after-standby-rotation

Answer (score 3):

You could try overriding onSaveInstanceState method.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                mContentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(
                        savedInstanceState, "mContent");
            }
            if (mContentFragment == null) {
                mContentFragment = new YourFragment();
            }
    }

    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "mContent",
            mContentFragment);
    }
```

Comment: How do I get `mContentFragment`?

Comment: Just new an instance of your Fragment.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't do `getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "mContent",
            mContentFragment);` because I don't know which Fragment is inside the `FragmentManager`. Fragments are managed by `TabPageIndicator` and I don't know a way to retrieve the array of Fragments contained in `FragmentManager` to save their state. I'm using the ViewPagerIndicator library so the fragment management totally depends on it.

Comment: There is a sample code in ApiDemos called FragmentTabs may helps.

Comment: In ApiDemos they use tabs in the `ActionBar`.`ActionBar` draws a `Spinner` instead of tabs when the device is in landscape mode but I need tabs, not a spinner.